# C Pointer of array of strings garbled when retreived later

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have read a lot of the answers on the theoretical issues with memory allocation to pointer to arrays, but have not been able to fix my code...so turning to you.

I have an array of strings in a STRUCT, which I need to write to and read from. Declared as:

```
typedef struct client_mod
{    
/* Client ad_file */
 char *ad_filenames[10];
/* Client's current ad array index*/
unsigned int ad_index;

} client;
```

Then , inside a function , I assign values to pointer:

```
static int get_spots (client_mod *client)
{

char buf[512];
FILE *ptr;

if ((ptr = popen("php /media/cdn/getspot.php", "r")) != NULL) {
/* Read one byte at a time, up to BUFSIZ - 1 bytes, the last byte will be used for null termination. */
size_t byte_count = fread(buf, 1, 512 - 1, ptr);
/* Apply null termination so that the read bytes can be treated as a string. */
buf[byte_count] = 0;
}

(void) pclose(ptr);

// parse  extracted string here...
int i = 0;
client->ad_filenames[i] = strdup(strtok(buf,"|"));

while(client->ad_filenames[i]!= NULL && i<5)
  {
  client->ad_filenames[++i] = strdup(strtok(NULL,"|"));
  if (client->ad_filenames[i] != NULL && strlen(client->ad_filenames[i]) > 5)    {
  LOG("TESTING FOR CORRECT FILE NAMES %s\n", client->ad_filenames[i]);
  }
 }

}
```

The problem comes when I retreive the values later:

```
/* in looping code block */

 LOG("Checking file under index = %d, file is %s", client->ad_index,  client->ad_filenames[client->ad_index]);
```

The first two members of the array are retreived normally, everything after that is garbled. 
I would appreciate any guidance. Thanks!
I understand this probablby comes from undefined behaviour of assigning directly to the pointer, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: We need to see more code. Why do you need an array of 10 pointers? Where are the values you are assigning those pointers coming from?

Comment: `var1` is probably declared as `char var1[some_size]`, yes? If so you should read up on scope and automatic storage duration.

Comment: What type etc. is 'var1'?  If it's a pointer to a malloced array into which the string data has been copied, fine, else....

Comment: Inside of the function func(), are you assigning it to string storage defined within the scope of func() - as automatic variables?  If so, those variables only have meaning while func() is executing.  Once func() returns, they're going to be undefined garbage.  You can make the string storage global, or statically defined within func().  Or use malloc/strdup.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with assigning to this struct element.

```
 char *ad_filenames[10];
```

ad_filenames is an array of 10 of pointer to characters.

What that means is that memory allocation is needed for each index.

Something like
      client->ad_filenames[0] = strdup(var1);

strdup() does both malloc() and strcpy() within this function.

client should be a variable name.  You already defined client as a type.

Here is working code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 typedef struct client_mod
 {    
    /* Client ad_file */
   char *ad_filenames[10];
    /* Client's current ad array index*/
   unsigned int ad_index;

 }CLIENT1;

 CLIENT1 *client;


 int func( char *var1 ) {
   client->ad_filenames[0] = strdup(var1);
 }

 int
 main(void)
 {
     char str1[10];
     client = malloc( sizeof client );

     strcpy( str1, "Hello" );
     func( str1 );

     printf("%s\n", client->ad_filenames[0] );

     free(client->ad_filenames[0]);
     free (client);

}
```

Comment: Thank you - will test it now and report asap.

Comment: you only use ad_filenames[0], no indexing. notice in the code, client->ad_filenames[i] = strdup(strtok(buf,"|"));

Comment: This  was just an illustration on the usage of strdup().  It wasn't never meant to be a complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the line,

```
size_t byte_count = fread(buf, 1, 1000 - 1, ptr);
```

Read the man fread page,

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

you read 1000-1 members of size 1 into buf, which is only allocated buf[512], either expand buf or decrease fread 3rd argument,

```
buf[1000+1];
size_t byte_count = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf)-1, ptr);
```

Comment: Thank you - that was a typo while moving code here; the underlying issue was the one Nguai-al pointed out.

Comment: The code snippet you provided had strdup. And you also typedef'ed a type 'client', but used it as the name of a pointer argument.